# IPhone launch application with home button

Tags: iphone, launch

do you know  in which ways is it possible to launch an application?

I know  that it is possible by clicking on the icon, and it is possible  by clicking an url with a cistom protocol,

Anyone know if there ae more ways?

For example is it possible to make  an application be launched when the users touch 3 times the home button?

or when the user start  a call?

thank you

Paolo

Answer (score 2):

The only ways that it is possible to launch an application are the ways you describe:

- Clicking the application's icon
- Via a custom URL scheme

The above applies to non-jailbroken iPhones. I would imagine it is techinically possible to hack a jail-broken iPhone to launch apps in other ways, but naturally such functionality would not be permitted on the App Store

Answer (score 1):

Jailbroken phones can use libactivator. It has a set of predefined touch and physical button events that can start an application. Of course it is not viable if you plan to publish your app in the store.